# does static var get automatic 0 values PHP?

Tags: php

I understand the use of static inside of a function.

But what I don't understand in the next example, why the variable `$x` can be incremented (like it was initialized to zero):

```
function print_conditional() {
    static $x;

    if($x++ == 1) {
        echo "things";

    } else {
        echo "good ";
    } 
}

print_conditional();
print_conditional();
echo PHP_EOL;
```

This will output "good things"

So, the first time the function is called, the variable `$x` with no value doesn't match in the if, but the second time, look likes it was incremented to 1 and match, how is that possible?

Comment: Tried echoing it out in each iteration to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Decrementing NULL values has no effect, but incrementing them results in 1.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)